# Update grid's width based on text in textblock in child control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this structure for a progressbar as below.

```
 <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="300">
         <ProgressBar Maximum="1.0" Minimum="0.0" Value="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
         <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5,0" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </Grid> </DataTemplate>
```

I want to update the width of Grid if the text in textblock is trimmed or has actual width which is greather than grid's width.

I tried few things like passing width to converter and bindings but I am unable to find a way around.

Comment: Why are you setting the `Width` property of the `Grid` in the first place if you want to it to depend on the width of the `TextBlock`?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a [ColumnDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.columndefinition) and set its [Width](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.columndefinition.width) to [Auto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.gridlength):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="300" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Padding="5,0"
                Text="{Binding Text}"/>
</Grid>
```

When your TextBlock grows beyond 300 pixels wide, the column width will adjust.